# Help with a double integral

Tags: area, multiple-integral

I'm not calculating the following integral correctly, but can't for the life of me find what I've done wrong.

Here's my work:

$$ \int_0^{13} \int_0^{\sqrt{169-x^2} } dy\ dx $$
$$ \int_0^{13} \sqrt{169-x^2} dx $$
$$ x^2\ +\ y^2 =\ r^2 $$
$$ x\ =\ r\ cos\ \theta $$
$$ y\ =\ r\ sin\ \theta $$
$$ r^2\ cos^2\ \theta\ +\ r^2\ sin^2\ \theta\ =\ r^2 $$
$$ r\ =\ 13 $$
$$ 13^2\ cos^2\ \theta\ +\ 13^2\ sin^2\ \theta\ =\ 13^2 $$
$$ 13\ sin\ \theta\ =\ \sqrt{13^2\ -\ 13^2\ cos^2\ \theta\ }\ =\ \sqrt{169\ - x^2\ } $$
$$ 13\ \int_\alpha^{\beta} sin\ \theta\ d\theta $$
$$ \theta(x)\ =\ cos^{-1}\ (\ \frac{x}{13}\ ) $$
$$ \theta(0)\ =\ cos^{-1}\ (\ \frac{0}{13}\ )\ =\ \frac{\pi}{2}\ =\ \beta $$
$$ \theta(13)\ =\ cos^{-1}\ (\ \frac{13}{13}\ )\ =\ 0\ =\ \alpha $$
$$ 13\ \int^{\pi\ /\ 2}_{0} sin\ \theta\ d\theta $$
$$ 13\ [\ -cos\ (\frac{\pi}{2})\ +\ cos\ (0)\ ] $$
$$ 13 $$

However, this integral should be the area of a circle radius 13 in the first quadrant. In other words:

$$ \frac{ 169\ \pi }{4} $$

Somewhere, I've made a mistake--but can't seem to spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to replace $\mathrm{d}x$ by $13 \sin(\theta)\, \mathrm{d}\theta.$

The integral of $\sin(\theta)^2$ accounts for the missing factor of $\frac{\pi}{4}.$